# @ControllerAdvice even by setting the highest precedense for RestControllers not working as it should

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, exception

I am using SpringBoot 5.
I want to catch all exception thrown from `RestController` and display  customize message format.
I have simplified the situation like below:
The RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestRestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> findById(@PathVariable int id) {
        Test test = testService.find(id);
        if(department!=null){
              throw CustomException();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(test, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

The ControllerAdvice Exception handler:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) 
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(value= {CustomException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetail> handleCustomException(CustomException exception,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        ErrorDetail errorDetail = new ErrorDetail();
        errorDetail.setTimeStamp(Instant.now().getEpochSecond());
        errorDetail.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        errorDetail.setTitle("Resource Not Found");
        errorDetail.setDetail(exception.getMessage());
        errorDetail.setDeveloperMessage(exception.getClass().getName());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetail, null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

The problem it is that `RestExceptionHandler` is not working, it is not catching the exception and returning the modified error message format. It seem my `RestExceptionControllerClass` is not overriding the `GlobalExceptionHandler`. I don't know why this is happening because I have marked the `RestExceptionHandler` with the highest precedense. I will appriciate any guidence to debug this problem.

Comment: Thank for your responses, the problem was that I hadn't checked that was another part in my code that was throwing an error which wasn't handle in my custom exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that another exception was thrown before my `CustomException`. In the service call , there was part of code that threw an exception that i did not expect. So my RestExceptionHandler couldn't catch the exception because it didn't have a method to handle that exception and so the `GlobalExceptionHandler`  was handling that exception. After fixing the code and made sure that the `CustomExeption` was thrown everything worked as it should. The `RestExceptionHandler` handled exception and printed the custom message.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `RestExceptionHandler` class like below

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetail> handleCustomException(CustomException exception) {
        ErrorDetail errorDetail = new ErrorDetail();
        errorDetail.setTimeStamp(Instant.now().getEpochSecond());
        errorDetail.setTitle("Resource Not Found");
        errorDetail.setDetail(exception.getMessage());
        errorDetail.setDeveloperMessage(exception.getClass().getName());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetail, null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

And you also need to extends `RuntimeException` in your `CustomException` class

Answer (score 0):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
    public ErrorDetail handleCustomException(CustomException exception) {
        ErrorDetail errorDetail = new ErrorDetail();
        errorDetail.setTimeStamp(Instant.now().getEpochSecond());
        errorDetail.setTitle("Resource Not Found");
        errorDetail.setDetail(exception.getMessage());
        errorDetail.setDeveloperMessage(exception.getClass().getName());
        return errorDetail;
    }
}
```

Refer this link to know more about exception handling for REST API
https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring