# How to create global exception handler

Tags: actframework

In actframework, we can use `@catch` to handle exception, but it's only working in current class and parent class. What can i do if i want to create a global exception handler, just like `@ExceptionHandler` in `SpringBoot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `@Global` annotation to your `@Catch` method, e.g.

```java
public class AppExceptionHandler {
    @Global
    @Catch(value = Throwable.class, priority = 1)
    public void logThrowable(Throwable throwable) {
        AppEntry.LOGGER.error(throwable, "Global Exception Handler: %s", throwable.getMessage());
    }
}
```

With the given code above, it will catch exception triggered in any request handler, e.g,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ControllerAdvice to create Global Exception Handler in spring boot. Below answer has sample code snippet that explains the same.

[@ControllerAdvice even by setting the highest precedense for RestControllers not working as it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782921/controlleradvice-even-by-setting-the-highest-precedense-for-restcontrollers-not/61784121#61784121)

Comment: The question is not about SpringBoot

Comment: Sorry my bad. I overlooked it